# creating a hierarchy from parent child relationship

Tags: c++

I extracted parent child relationship from an xml file. The only assumption is that ROOT is the parent node. The rest of the nodes are all over the place. A sample data set is as per below:

```
PARENT  | CHILD

DEL     | 4568
ZPER    | CF00
D034    | SDCX
ROOT    | L3NP
D034    | SLGH
L3NP    | AZQW
DEL     | 31SW
ROOT    | D034
SLGH    | DFGT
L3NP    | ZPER
DEL     | DFRT
ROOT    | DEL
```

I stored this data in a vector:

```
struct t{
    string p; /* parent */
    string c; /* child, child can be a parent of another node */
};

vector<t> tree;

tree.push_back(t());
tree[tcntr].p=prnt;
tree[tcntr].c=chld;
```

I am not sure how to keep track of the levels at which each of the members are found. Maybe there is a standard approach to trying to generate the hierarchy that I am not aware of and would appreciate the help in pointing me in the right direction.

In the end the output should look like this:

```
ROOT            
 >  L3NP        
    >  AZQW 
    >  ZPER 
           >  CF00
 >  D034        
    >  SDCX 
    >  SLGH 
           >  DFGT
 >  DEL     
    >  4568 
    >  31SW 
    >  DFRT
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a recursive function. I don't know how you store the values you showed, but we could use `std::unordered_multimap` for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using Map = std::unordered_multimap<std::string, std::string>;

struct Node {
  std::string name = {};
  std::vector<Node> children = {};
};

Node MakeTree(Map const& map, std::string const& nodeName) {
  Node node{nodeName};

  auto const rng = map.equal_range(nodeName);

  for (auto it = rng.first; it != rng.second; ++it)
    node.children.push_back(MakeTree(map, it->second));

  return node;
}

void Print(Node const& n, unsigned lvl = 0) {
  printf("%*c %s\n", lvl * 2, '>', n.name.c_str());

  for (auto const& child : n.children)
    Print(child, lvl + 1);
}

int main() {
  Map const map = {
      {"DEL", "4568"},  {"ZPER", "CF00"}, {"D034", "SDCX"}, {"ROOT", "L3NP"},
      {"D034", "SLGH"}, {"L3NP", "AZQW"}, {"DEL", "31SW"},  {"ROOT", "D034"},
      {"SLGH", "DFGT"}, {"L3NP", "ZPER"}, {"DEL", "DFRT"},  {"ROOT", "DEL"},
  };

  Node const tree = MakeTree(map, "ROOT");
  Print(tree);
}
```

Output:

```
> ROOT
 > L3NP
   > AZQW
   > ZPER
     > CF00
 > D034
   > SDCX
   > SLGH
     > DFGT
 > DEL
   > 4568
   > 31SW
   > DFRT
```